# Decoding h264 stream from gstreamer on iOS

Tags: ios8, gstreamer, h.264

I have iOS app which can receive and decode annex b h264 stream

I have a device with camera which streams h264 with gstreamer in AVC format

Can I make gstreamer stream in annex b format ?

OR

How do I extract the sequence header (or the sep file) from gstreamer ?

Answer (score 0):

Annex-B format is simply NAL unit with exactly the 4 byte magic sequence begining a NAL unit: 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01.

Remember H.264 NAL units can be of 3 of 4 bytes for their magic sequence. If you write your own parser you can handle this by doing something like:

```
size_t lastNaluStartingOffset = frameSize + 1;
for (size_t i = 0; i < frameSize - 10; ++i) {
    if (frameBuffer[i] == ZERO_BYTE && frameBuffer[i+1] == ZERO_BYTE && frameBuffer[i+2] == MAGIC_BYTE) {
        uint32_t naluType = (frameBuffer[i+3] & 0x1F);

        NaluSegment *segment = [[NaluSegment alloc] initWithType:naluType atOffset:i withHeaderSize:3];
        if (i > 0 && frameBuffer[i-1] == ZERO_BYTE) {
            // its actally a 4 byte code!
            [segment setOffset:[segment offset]-1];
            [segment setHeaderSize:4];
        }
....
```

Now you are free to format your NAL unit as you like.